# vertical align:middle isn't working in my div tag

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

Vertical-align:middle isn't working
I'm trying to get the text `Starbucks Coffee Company` aligned with the logo 
here: `file:///Users/DD12/Desktop/Nicole's%20website/index.html#`

**This the HTML**

```
<html> 
   <body>
     <div class="header">
     <p style="color:#FFF;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; font-size:45px ; font-
     family:'Franklin Gothic'">Starbucks Coffee Company</p>  </div>
   <body> 
</html>
```

**This is the CSS**

```
.header {
   background-color: #ADB96E;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: we can't see that file. It's local to your computer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!  The image in your post is a link to a file on your own computer, which we can't see.  Try uploading it to [imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com) or another site and edit your question to have that link instead.  Someone with more rep will edit your question to display the image.

Comment: i do,n't see your picture in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The property "vertical-align" just work with an element inline.

test this code :

```
.header {
   background-color: #ADB96E;
   vertical-align:middle;
   display:inline-block;
   width: 100%

}
```